# I am trying to Detecting Incoming Phone Calls In Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I just want to show a toast when a call is received, But nothing is happening and it doesn't even stop on `OnReceive` in debugging mode. 
I am unable to figure out that why it is not getting stopped at the onReceive. It is just like it is not even receiving an intent .

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.rajatgupta.broadcastrecieverexample">



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="MyReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="rajat_action">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCall">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">
            </action>
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

**IncomingCall.java**

```
public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context mContext;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      try {
   Log.d("Intent", "Intent Detected");
    Toast.makeText(context," Receiver start     ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer enough to just to put the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in the Manifest, you now have to request permissions at runtime.

Permission check:
`int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);`

Request:
`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);`

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html